# How to add image to ImageView in iOS storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview, storyboard

Is there a way to add a default image to an imageView through the storyboard? I UIImageView in question is a view inside a TableViewCell. I can't seem to find the option in the storyboard, and I am convinced this kind of option should definitely exist.

Comment: When you select the image view, the first field at the top of the "attributes Inspector" tab is "Image". That's where you set it.

Comment: @rdelmar Ha, Thanks! Yes, I finally saw it.

Answer (score 5):

I finally see it under Attributes Inspector. I can also drag and drop from Media Library (basically the same place where I select my views): in case someone else is lost.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a UITableViewCell, give a tag to the image view:

```
UIImageView *myimage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
myimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename"];
```